# Multiple button presses for Android 2.x

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am relatively new to this still, and I have been developing a small app that would benefit greatly from a user being able to press 2 buttons at one time. What is the best method for achieving this? I dont think that an OnClickListener works like that, and I have seen examples for doing this with an OnTouch event. However, I do not know how to set up button presses with an OnTouch event.

Answer (score 5):

You would have to handle touch events yourself. With the multi-pointers (aka multi-touch) API it's very easy. Just override the onTouchEvent() method or register an OnTouchListener on your buttons.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the info. The only problem I am running across is how to implement an OnTouchListener for multiple buttons. Am I to set an OnTouchListener for every one? Or can I set a single listener, and use a switch statement like switch(v.getId()) R.id.button1:..... R.id.button2:......

Comment: nm, I figured it out :) Thanks again!

Comment: By the way Romain - if you're 'the' Romain Guy from Google, could you try to stick to using one account on Stack Overflow? You appear to use up to 5 accounts, most of them new and with low reputation. That makes it hard for people to know whether the answers they're getting are 'official' and very reliable, or simply the opinion of someone who happens to share the same name as the guy (no pun intended) at Google.

Comment: Ok, so this is what I have so far. I have set an OnTouchListener for each of my buttons, and here is the code for the event: http://pastebin.com/10RyhKx0  The buttons operate just fine, I just cannot click more than 1 at a time

Comment: Steve H., I am 'the' Romain Guy but StackOverflow was too annoying when I tried to login with existing accounts :)

Comment: Steve, I've created a real account, this should help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // reset all buttons
        ...
    }
    else {
        int count=event.getPointerCount(),vx1=-1,vy1=-1,vx2=-1,vy2=-1;
        if (count>=1) {
            vx1=(int)event.getX(0);
            vy1=(int)event.getY(0);
        }
        if (count>=2) {
            vx2=(int)event.getX(1);
            vy2=(int)event.getY(1);
        }
        ...
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: probably Lohoris what biquillo was saying is that your example shows only the coordinates, but does not show how you can get the button under those coordinates. When you receive a MotionEvent with multiple pointers to a call onTouchEvent(View view, MotionEvent) the view is one of the two buttons