# Press buttons at the same time

Tags: android

I need to handle multiple button presses in a gui on the screen at the same time. I have looked everywhere and tried to implement my own listeners and everything without success. Any hint?

Thank in advance!!

Comment: Is the screen where you are running the proof of concept multi-touch?

Comment: yes i just edited my question

Comment: [Is this of any help ?](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747)

Comment: Reno, in that site they play with canvas, I need multitouch in gui elements. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: [Got it. Let me know if this works for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528160/multiple-button-presses-for-android-2-x)

Comment: Reno thanks again for your comment. I tried it sometime ago and did not work for me. Could it be that its just my phone (Samsung Galaxy S) or something? Anyway I havent seen any app that allows multitouch in GUI elements on the market. :(