# How to get button event while finger moving -android

Tags: android, button, multi-touch

Im working on a piano app. I placed 6 buttons and just want to play series of sound while moving finger on this buttons? AFAIK android doesn't detect event when finger touched on one button and crossed to another button..
I tried sample code for multi touch on button that works okay.. but it wont work while finger is moving..

Anybody has come across this type of problem or can any1 just give a hint how to do this? TIA.

Comment: see this Link here   u can get an idea


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528160/multiple-button-presses-for-android-2-x